# UINavigationItem titleView position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uinavigationitem

I'm using UINavigationItem's titleView property to set a custom UILabel with my desired font size/color. Here's my code:

```
self.headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 44.0)];
self.headerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
self.headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
self.headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.259 green:0.280 blue:0.312 alpha:1.0];
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.headerLabel;
```

In the navigation bar I also have a left bar button. The result is: the text isn't properly centered. I've tried setting the x origin of the label, but this has no effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you make the headerLabel a subview of the titleView, you can then set headerLabel's frame to control where it goes within the titleView.

The way you are doing it now, you don't have that control.  I think the OS chooses the titleView's frame for you based on the space available.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, I tried this but my titleView is getting push down slightly when I have a button on the left or right. Were you able to prevent this from happening?

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, what am I doing wrong here? The headerLabel doesn't appear at all when I do  [self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:headerLabel];.  Do I need to set the titleView to something first?

Comment: If it's not working, write it up as a new question, explain what you are doing, and link to this question.

Comment: The answer is wrong. Per the documentation **This property is ignored if leftBarButtonItem is not nil.**

Comment: You helped me alot! Want to upvote ten times!! The label really goes everywhere )

Answer (score 20):

In stead of `initWithFrame` just use `init` and put `[self.headerLabel sizeToFit]` *after* your last line of code.

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but I can see how someone might argue that it doesn't answer the question asked, but offers a useful tangential trick.

Answer (score 4):

I've used custom title labels for my nav bars in every app I have in the app store. I've tested many different ways of doing so and by *far* the easiest way to use a custom label in a navigation bar is to completely ignore `titleView` and insert your label directly into `navigationController.view`.

With this approach, it's easy to have the title label's frame always match the navigationBar's frame -- even if you are using a custom navBar with a non-standard size.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.titleLabel];
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
             (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   return YES;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
             (UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
   [self frameTitleLabel];
}

- (UILabel *) titleLabel {
   if (!titleLabel) {
      titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]           
          initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame];

       titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
       titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Custom Title", nil);
       titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
       titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
   }
   return titleLabel;
}

- (void) frameTitleLabel {
   self.titleLabel.frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
}
```

The one caveat to this approach is that your title can flow over the top of any buttons you have in the navBar if you aren't careful and set the title to be too long. But, IMO, that is a lot less problematical to deal with than 1) The title not centering correctly when you have a rightBarButton or 2) The title not appearing if you have a leftBarButton.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 

As a note, when I implemented your approach, the created view did not disappear when pressing the back button.

Answer (score 3):

I have a same problem; I just somehow solved this issue by calculating the title length and set the label frame width accordingly. Although this is not a perfect one but can be manageable. Here is the code.

```
label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"XXII DIRTY-ARMY" size: 32.0 ];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0f];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor =[UIColor orangeColor];
//label.text=categoryTitle;
CGFloat verticalOffset = 2; 
NSString *reqSysVer = @"5.0";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)           
{
    if (categoryTitle.length > 8)
    {
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44);
    }else {
        label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 44);
    }

    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;  
     self.navigationItem.title=label.text;
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:verticalOffset   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
     [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor newBrownLight]];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate exact frame size needed and align to left:

```
UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitsumishi" size:20];
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [title sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap]; 
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height);
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
label.font = font;
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
label.text = title;
self.titleView = label;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *vw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
lbl.text = @"Home";
lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20];
lbl.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lbl.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
self.navigationItem.titleView = vw;
[self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:lbl];
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to update the titleView frame in the viewDidAppear method.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIView *titleView = self.navigationItem.titleView;
    CGRect navBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    [titleView setFrame:CGRectMake((CGRectGetWidth(navBarFrame) - TitleWidth) / 2, (CGRectGetHeight(navBarFrame) - TitleHeight) / 2, TitleWidth, TitleHeight)];
}
```