# UINavigationItem#titleView alignment problems

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am finding little information about using UINavigationItem#titleView with a custom font.
When I have done so, the font is misaligned vertically in the navigation bar.

This entry is partly to document a hack, and also hoping someone has a succinct answer to this problem, as I feel I am missing something simple.

First the hack, using my own UILabel derived class:

```
@interface NavigationItemLabel : UILabel
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame;
@end

@implementation NavigationItemLabel
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    // Called by UINavigationBar layoutSubviews.
    frame.origin.y -= self.font.descender;
}
@end
```

For some reason, frame.origin.y == -11, no matter what font I use.
Does anyone have any intuition as to why this is?

Adding my font's descender (custom font called Gabriola) seems to help. Without this hack, the text is aligned with the bottom of the descenders on the center of the navigation bar.

This doesn't work for all fonts.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: A possible clue is Sjors Provoost's suggestion to use sizeToFit regarding a related question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125245/uinavigationitem-titleview-position)

Answer (score 3):

If you are deploying to iOS 5+, you could check out the `titleVerticalPositionAdjustmentForBarMetrics` property the in the [UINavigationBar documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html):

```
- (CGFloat)titleVerticalPositionAdjustmentForBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
Returns the title’s vertical position adjustment for given bar metrics.
```

Also, you should check out `titleTextAttributes` (also iOS5+), which you can use to set a custom font:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
    UITextAttributeFont: yourFont
};
[navBar setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
```

If you're **NOT** on iOS5, I'd suggest wrapping the `UILabel` inside a `UIView` and setting your UIView as `titleView` instead (this allows you to further adjust the wrapped label's position by changing its `frame`).

If you have access to the WWDC 2012 videos (i.e. if you've got a developer account), I'd strongly recommend watching the talk on [Advanced Appearance Customization on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=216) (this stuff is included there).

Hope it helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using `Grotesque` and there was a great SO solution shown by @kolyuchiy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8314285/392653).  (It involves downloading the [Apple Font Tool Suite](http://developer.apple.com/fonts/) command line utilities and adjusting the `ascender` attribute for your custom font).